# Should I reuse tableView cells when they have little difference?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I just want to know which is the better way to do cell reuse
For example:

Cell 1:

- Name
- Detail
- Time

Cell 2:

- Name
- Detail
- Image
- Time

The two cells, "Name","Detail","Time" are having the same position.
So, my questions are:

1. Shall I use one cell for reuse(modify constraint in runtime) or create two separate cells?
2. I think use two cell will have the better performance, but how to reuse the "Name","Detail","Time"'s auto layout in xib (If use code, this is easy for me, but my project use xib)

Comment: Is cell 1 appearing multiple times or is that a header cell?

Comment: "but how to reuse the "Name","Detail","Time"'s auto layout in xib" Just do it separately in each xib. You don't need to "reuse" any auto layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options.

- use stack view, then manipulating constraints is not needed to hide a element.  Lets you only create one storyboard/IB instance and stack view handles hiding nicely.
- use two unique cells, they can grow over time down separate paths as requirements change.

Or my preference

- create cell subclass, lets say BaseCell, that loads object or
  protocol that can supply name/detail/time, cell.load(xxx)
- create a cell that subclasses BaseCell, say ImageBaseCell, that loads
  an object that loads object or protocol that can supply
  name/detail/time/image, handle image here, but super.load(xxx) will
  handle the rest.

This does require individual xibs per cell subclass. However, this way, logic for handling name/detail/time is in one place, instead of several cell classes.

Comment: thanks for answer.I think your xib+subclass is the best way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend for going with two separate cells. The table view datasource methods will take care of populating the cell contents rather than you handling the views inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Also if you're incorporating contents of varying sizes in the a cell, it is always better to go with multiple cells for cells having different contents.